# I have a function inside a main function, but when I run it I get a TypeError: 'builtin_function_or_method' object is not iterable

Tags: python, typeerror

```
def read_file(filename): 
    results = []
    data ={}
    with open(filename, 'r') as h:
        for line in h:
           four_vals = line.split(',')
           batch = four_vals[0]
           if not batch in data:
               data[batch] = []
           data[batch] += [float(four_vals[1]), float(four_vals[2]), float(four_vals[3])] 
           results.append(four_vals)
    return results 

def check_statement(x,y): 
    if x**2 + y**2 <= 1:
        return True
    else:
        return False 

def calculate_values(sample): 
        n = 0
        x_sum = 0
        for (x, y, val) in sample:
            if check_statement(x,y):
                x_sum += val
                n += 1
            
        return x_sum/n  
def main():
    
    filename = input('Which csv file should be analyzed? ')
    data = {}
    read_file(filename)
    print("Batch \t Average")
    
    for batch, sample in data.items:
        results = calculate_values(sample)
        print(batch, "\t", results)
```

when I put in a doc it should calculate the average and give the batch like this:

```
Which csv file should be analyzed? sample1.csv
Batch    Average
1    87.0
2    17.0
```

Comment: It should be `for batch, sample in data.items():`

Comment: `data.items` is a method.  You forgot to put parentheses `()` after the method name.

Comment: Also, `data` is an empty dictionary, so that for loop will never execute.  The local variable `data` in the `main()` function has no connection to the local variable `data` inside the `read_file()` function...

Comment: @JohnGordon, probably they mean that, but `read_file` returns list `results`, so plenty of problems here

Answer (score 1):

You are using the items method of a dictionary without calling it.
Change this line:

```
for batch, sample in data.items:
```

To this:

```
for batch, sample in data.items():
```

Comment: so I have updated my code to this:

Comment: def read_file(filename): # this function will read the file first
    global data
    data ={}
    with open(filename, 'r') as h:
        for line in h:
           four_vals = line.split(',')
           global batch 
           batch = four_vals[0]
           global x
           x = four_vals[1]
           global y
           y = four_vals[2]
           global val
           val = four_vals[3]
           if not batch in data:
               data[batch] = []
           data[batch] += [(float(x), float(y), float(val))]# Collect data from an experiment
    return data

Comment: def check_statement(x,y): # this function checks if for x and y the statement is true
    if x**2 + y**2 <= 1:
        return True
    else:
        return False

Comment: def calculate_average(data):# this is a separate function for calculating
    for batch,sample in data.items():
        n = 0
        x_sum = 0
        for (x, y, val) in sample:
            if check_statement(x,y):
                x_sum += val
                n += 1
                global average
            average = x_sum/n

Comment: def main():
    # this will function as the main body of the program
    filename = input('Which csv file should be analyzed? ')
    data = {}
    data = read_file(filename)
    print("Batch \t Average")
    for batch, sample in data.items():
        calculate_average(data)
        print(batch, "\t", average)

Comment: but these is still something wrong with my calculate_average function, as it only returns o ne average and not all the averages of all the batches